# How to setup spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF flag in SparkConf running in EMR 6.3

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

Request you to please help me when I encounter an issue where I am not able to set "spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF" as true in SparkConf.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
sparkConf.setIfMissing("spark.master", "local[*]")
sparkConf.set("spark.executorEnv.spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF",true)
val session = SparkSession.builder()
  .config(sparkConf)
  //.config("spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF",true)
  .getOrCreate()
```

It gives me the following result:

```
[Error] D:\PassAddress.scala.12: type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean(true)
 required: String
one error found
```

And if I change it to string, then it doesn't shows its result:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    sparkConf.setIfMissing("spark.master", "local[*]")
    sparkConf.set("spark.executorEnv.spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF","true")
```

or if set the setting like below, still result is same. And I am not able to proceed further.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
sparkConf.setIfMissing("spark.master", "local[*]")
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF","true")
```

My objective is to set this environment flag, so that already existing functionality support Spark 3.0 onwards. Spark 3.0 onwards they removed the default support for UntypeScalaUDF.

Comment: try `spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF = true")`

Comment: @mck 
I tried with ```sparkConf.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF = true"``` . it didn't worked. :-(

Comment: use `spark` which is the `SparkSession`, not `sparkconf`.

Comment: @mck
I tested the code, but it seems it is not working in my case.
```
val session = SparkSession.builder()
      .config(sparkConf)
      .sql("set spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF = true")     
      .getOrCreate()
```
and it gave the below error:
```
value sql is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value sql'?
two errors found

```

Comment: initialise the spark session object in the variable `spark`, then call spark.sql on the session object.

Comment: It seems Spark 3.1.x onwards they drop the dynamic support for spark.sql.legacy.allowUntypedScalaUDF. Irrespective of whether you set up in SparkConf or in SparkSession.

Comment: @PraveenKumar.. how did you managed to resolve this